# Cassandra tombstones count multiple queries vs single query

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3

I've a cassandra table definition as following

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  colA text,
  colB text,
  timeCol timestamp,
  colC text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((colA, colB, timeCol), colC)
) WITH....
```

I want to know if number of tombstones would vary between following types of queries:

```
1. delete from mytable where colA = '...' AND colB = '...' and timeCol = 111
```

Above query affect multiple records, (multiple values of colC)

```
2. delete from mytable where colA = '...' AND colB = '...' and timeCol = 111 AND colC = '...'
```

However, 2nd query needs to be executed for each value of last column `colC`, while 1st query takes care of deletion in one execution

Will Cassandra create same number of tombstones in both the cases?

Comment: Is there a tool using which I could inspect the tombstones created in Cassandra? That could help answer my question very easily.

Comment: You can use the following tool to inspect your sstables (you may also have to use `nodetool flush`): http://datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSStable2json_t.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra will create a single tombstone for each delete statement. However, each statement will create a different type of tombstone.

`1. delete from mytable where colA = '...' AND colB = '...' and timeCol = 111`

Will create a row level tombstone:

`{
"key": "00032e2e2e0000032e2e2e000008000000000000006f00",
"metadata": {
  "deletionInfo": {
    "markedForDeleteAt":1427461335167000,"localDeletionTime":1427461335
  }
},
"columns": []
}`

Row level tombstones will make sure all columns will be covered with the delete.

`2. delete from mytable where colA = '...' AND colB = '...' and timeCol = 111 AND colC = '...'`

Creates a column tombstone:

`{
"key": "00032e2e2e0000032e2e2e000008000000000000006f00",
"columns": [["...","...:!",1427461572135000,"t",1427461572]]
}`

This will only delete values that have been saved under this clustering key.

Comment: For a combination of colA, colB, timeCol i.e. [a,b, 1111] , I've 4 values of colC. So, the data is like following:

colA | colB | timeCol | colC
----------------------------------
a | b | 111 | c1,
a | b | 111 | c2,
a | b | 111 | c3,
a | b | 111 | c4
-----
Delete using only 1st 3 columns {.. where colA = 'a' and colB = 'b' and timeCol = 111}
------
Delete using all 4 columns {...where colA = 'a' and colB = 'b' and timeCol = 111 and colC = 'c1' } and run it 4 times with different value of colC.

Are you saying that no. of tombstones will be 4 in 2nd query-set and only 1 tombstone in 1st query?

Comment: Yes, you get a tombstone for each value of colC.