# Cassandra delete performance depends on number of tombstones or number of cells?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I've a cassandra table definition as following

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  colA text,
  colB text,
  timeCol timestamp,
  colC text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((colA, colB, timeCol), colC)
) WITH....
```

When I delete using 2 different queries:

```
1. delete from mytable where colA = '...' AND colB = '...' and timeCol = 111
2. delete from mytable where colA = '...' AND colB = '...' and timeCol = 111 AND colC = '...'
```

there are different types and numbers of tombstones getting generated. Refer here
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/29301627/1439122

Given that same number of rows are affected in eventual clearing/compaction, does the performance of compaction process depend on number and type of tombstones or just the number of rows/cells getting affected?

Answer (score 1):

`1` is a range tombstone, and `2` is a cell tombstone. I could be wrong but I think its negligible for most use cases.  `1` may cause more tombstones or data thrown away on reads (slightly harder on jvm) if theres many values of colC. Of the two I suspect `2` to be (slightly) more efficient if theres only one value of colC but `1` far better to delete all colC's in the a/b/time partition.

I guess a "it depends" and "probably doesn't matter".

Comment: There would be typically 5 values of colC (and thereby 5 records in the table) for a given combination of colA, colB, timeCol.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any performance impact as long as you scan too much through tombstones for your reads post delete .

In most cases, making a partition deletion will give you better performance as you are not concerned about that partition anymore.

Using cell deletes, you create fragments ,which won't die for gc_grace_seconds anyway. Internal fragmentation creates problems for your application as well as Cassandra. Just consider a GC on Cassandra side with  internally fragmented data. That's what you will end up in.